# keep database flag 1 until item expiry date between in CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to keep database flag `30dexpf = 1` until expiry date of item is equal to or in between up coming 7 days and 30 days
Here is my database table

```
30dexpf | expiry
--------|--------
0       | 2016-12-15 14:18:00
0       | 2016-12-17 14:18:00
```

As far I know it can be something like this:

```
$query="UPDATE user_pages
SET `30dexpf` = CASE
                WHEN (
                    DATE(expiry) = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
                ) THEN 1 ELSE   0 END;";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following query:

```
UPDATE user_pages
SET 
    `30dexpf` = 1
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(expiry, CURDATE()) >= 7 AND DATEDIFF(expiry, CURDATE()) <= 30;
```

It will update all the records whose expiry date in between 7 to 30 days from the current date.

Comment: perfect it's working, <br>$query="UPDATE user_pages SET `30dexpf` = 1 WHERE DATEDIFF(expiry, CURDATE()) >= 7 AND DATEDIFF(expiry, CURDATE()) <= 30;"; but one problem since we're not using condition how to revert flag back to = 0 in case condition fail

Comment: Or, (DATEDIFF(expiry, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 7 AND 30);

Comment: @GoargeGo ignore the previous comment please `UPDATE st1 SET 30dexpf = CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(expiry, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 7 AND 30) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: +1 working perfect now ---> $query="UPDATE user_pages SET `30dexpf` = CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(expiry, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 8 AND 30) THEN 1 ELSE  0 END"; Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below query and see if it works for you ? It basically adds now + 7 to the lower limit and 30 to the higher limit and sets the flag to 1 if the date is between the two.

```
$query="UPDATE user_pages
         SET `30dexpf` = CASE
         WHEN (
          DATE(expiry) BETWEEN 
            DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
            AND DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
         THEN 1 ELSE   0 END;";
```

Comment: oh it's not working, it's returning same results as mine old query :(

Comment: let me try by replacing now with CURDATE() your query is good it should work )

Comment: I've checked this on one of my fields and it's working for me.